# How to make new button from existing one in adobe flash cs5.5?

Tags: flash, adobe

I have such a problem:
I have a MovieClip A1. And on this movie clip there are three movie clips buttons with instance names: b1, b2, b3.

I want to add new button, and I want it to be the same as 3 others, but with different image on it and with instance name b4. So I am taking button b1 make dublicate of it, edit that dublicate and put it to the movie clip A1 to other buttons with instance name b4. But after this nothing is workable. If I put there different button - all ok, in other way - it doesn't works. How can I add new button which looks like other three buttons? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy/duplicate the 'b1' and edit it as 'b4', because it will change your 'b1' too.
Because its like change your class.

try it:
Right click your 'b1', click on 'Duplicate Symbols...', then rename it (you got a new class)
then you can change the picture without make changes on 'b1'